# Verification Code Every Login

Tags: login

Every time I log in I get a Verification Code sent to my email address. Is there a way to fix this behavior?

Comment: Did you try adding your ip address to Salesforce network access?

Comment: No, i did't... even i don't know how to add ip address..

Comment: can yo help me how to do it?

Comment: First find your ip address by searching google with "what's my ip address" then copy result. Then login to salesforce go to Setup --> Quick Find. Search for Network Address. Click the result than click New button. Paste your ip address to start and end ip address input fields. then click save. After that Salesforce will not ask for verification code from your computer. (until your ip address changes, eg. your modem restarts.)

Answer (score 4):

You can whitelist your IP Address in Salesforce. This way you can skip verification code step. To add your IP address to Salesforce;

1. Find your ip address by searching google with "what's my ip address" then copy result.
2. Then login to salesforce go to Setup --> Quick Find.
3. Search for Network Access.
4. Click the result than click New button.
5. Paste your ip address to start and end ip address input fields. then click save.

After that Salesforce will not ask for verification code from your computer. (until your IP address changes, eg. your modem restarts.)

Comment: The IP address could view from the Salesforce `Login History`: source IP